# How do we prove $A=\mathbb{Z}$ if, $A=\{5x-3|x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm taking a course on proofs, and I encountered this kind of questions, based on method that is shown in the textbook, Iapplied same method as follows

---

To show $A=\mathbb{Z}$ I need to prove $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq A$

since $x \in \mathbb{Z}, 5x-3$ will also be a member of $\mathbb{Z}$, so this proves $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$

Suppose we have any $n \in\mathbb{Z}$

$n = \frac{5n}{5} +3 -3 $

Upon simplifying further we get $n = 5\left(\frac{n+3}{5}\right) - 3$, so here I have shown that any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, can be written in the form of $A$, so $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in A \implies \mathbb{Z} \subseteq A$

Is this correct? Or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: There is no integer $x$ such that $5x - 3 = 0$.

Comment: It is not in form of $A$, because $\frac{n + 3}{5}$ is not necessary integer. And the original claim is false: for example, $0 \notin A$.

Comment: Is it a typo? With $A=\{5x-3y\mid x,y\in \Bbb Z\}$ it works.

Comment: But i have a doubt $\frac{n+3}{5}$, is not necessary in $\mathbb{Z}$, it seems while i showed that n can be written in given form, but the variable $x = \frac{n+3}{5}$ seems to be going against the definition of $A$

Comment: @DietrichBurde your assumption is correct that in the book they have shown for two variables, but i was just trying to proof this for only single variable. I can do this right?

Comment: No, you can't. It is wrong, unfortunately.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, why not? Can you explain please?

Comment: Your set only represents the integers congruent $-3$ modulo $5$. So $A$ cannot be equal to $\Bbb Z$. Since the statement is false, its "proof" cannot be correct, too.

Comment: "I have a doubt $\frac{n + 3}{5}$ is not necessary in $\mathbb Z$" - try $n = 0$ - what number do you get? Is it in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: What is the exact question (as written in the textbook)? Maybe $A=\{\; 5x-3y\; |\; x,y\in\mathbb Z\; \}$ in which case it can be proved that $A=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Taladris yes they have shown in an example using two variables, i was trying to proof some random question using this, apprently i can't use it for single variables, I'm using the Richard Hammack book. Its in the first chapter

Comment: @Ace one of the main points of studying such things is that you will be able to check why you can or can't use some reasoning. So it's useful to understand where exactly is flaw in your argument (so you can see that example from book doesn't have such flaw). In this case, as several people already said, the problem is that when you write $n = 5\left(\frac{n+3}{5}\right) - 3$ - it doesn't allow you to find $x \in \mathbb Z$ s.t. $n = 5x - 3$.

Comment: @mihaild Thank you for your kind words, I will keep that in mind, I should have reviewed my proof for a while.

Comment: @Ace: I guessed it was Book of Proof by Hammack, as I am re-reading it for a course. Actually, there is a reason there is two variables (with a gcd of $1$): it gives you more flexibility to obtain every integer.

Comment: Anyway, it is a great working habit to try to modify examples to understand how things work. What you need to improve is to find the flawed step in your reasoning (as mihaild already explained)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your argument is that $\frac{n+3}5$, which takes the place of $x$ in the original formula, will not always be an integer (as others have pointed out).

In cases like this, always ask yourself if the thing serves as an example for something ($\frac{n+3}5$ here) is actually well defined and meets all the requirements. And since we work in the integers here, the answer is "it might not" (for some $n$ it works, but not for others).

Answer (score 0):

It is false , for example if $5x-3=1$

Then , $x=\frac{4}{5}\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.